# Proving an equivalence to the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

A set of sets A is said to be disjointed if $\forall C,D\in A, C\cap D =\varnothing $. Let F be a set of sets; prove that F has a maximal disjointed subset.
Prove that this statement is equivalent with the Axiom of Choice.

IDEA

My idea is to use
 Zorn's Lemma that says: Every inductive set has at least one maximal element.

Comment: Order the set of all disjoint subfamilies of $F$ by inclusion. Show this is an inductive PO.

Comment: Zorn's lemma sounds like an excellent plan. Which problems (if any) do you run into when you attempt to execute it?

Comment: That I do not see in an obvious way the implication with the axiom of choice.

Comment: Are you having a problem with the "if" part of the "iff" or the"only if" part?

Comment: I have problem with de iff

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the position of the "iff". The claim is phrased so convolutedly that taken verbatim it is false. (Otherwise we could prove that the Axiom of Choice holds simply by exhibiting an $F$ where we can explicitly show a maximal disjoint subset). The statement should be something like: "Prove that [every set of sets has a maximal disjoint subset] iff [the Axiom of Choice holds]". The difference is that the "iff" should be _outside_ the quantification over $F$. In this shape "if" is easily handled by Zorn's lemma, but "only if" doesn't seem to be.

Comment: The edit (revision 2) doesn't fix the wording problem. The problem is that when you say "Let $F$ be a set of sets", _everything that follows_ is in the scope of the $\forall F$, including the words "is equivalent [to]". We need the claim of equivalence to be _outside_ the scope of this quantification, and the only way to do that (in idiomatic mathematical English) is to get rid of the phrasing "Let $F$ be ..." to express the $\forall F$. That's why I suggested expressing it with "every set of sets" instead.

Comment: You should specify exactly what version of the Axiom of Choice you have (or what equivalents you have proven are equivalent).

Comment: Don't you mean "if $C\ne D$ then $C\cap D=\emptyset$"?

Comment: What text is this problem from? The wording in this post is a little unusual, which makes me wonder if the original text says something different.

Answer (score 3):

For the direction not covered by Zorn's Lemma, suppose we're given that every family of sets has a maximal disjointed subfamily, and suppose we're given a family $\mathcal F$ of nonempty sets; we intend to find a choice function for the family.

To simplify notation, assume, without loss of generality, that $\mathcal F$ is disjointed. (If it's not, replace each $A\in\mathcal F$ with $\{\langle A,a\rangle:a\in A\}$.)

For each given element $a\in\bigcup\mathcal F$, let $A_a$ be the element of $\mathcal F$ that contains $a$ (it's unique because $\mathcal F$ is disjointed), and let $Z_a$ be the set of all the sets $\{a,x\}$ where $a$ is our given element and $x\in A_a$. (So in nontrivial situations most of the elements of $Z_a$ will be $2$-element sets, but we also allow $x=a$.) Notice that $Z_a$ and $Z_b$ will be disjoint iff $A_a\neq A_b$, because if $A_a=A_b$ then $\{a,b\}$ is in both $Z_a$ and $Z_b$.

By hypothesis, $\{Z_a:a\in\bigcup\mathcal F\}$ has a maximal disjointed subfamily $\mathcal D$. By the observation at the end of the preceding paragraph, the set $C=\{a\in\bigcup\mathcal F:Z_a\in\mathcal D\}$ contains at most one $a$ from each $A\in\mathcal F$. Maximality easily implies that $C$ actually contains at least one $a$ from each $A\in\mathcal F$, because if it missed some $A\in\mathcal F$ then we could take an arbitrary $a\in A$ (remember that the sets in $\mathcal F$ are nonempty) and add $Z_a$ in to $\mathcal D$, contradicting maximality.

So $C$ contains exactly one element from each $A\in\mathcal F$ and we get the desired choice function by sending each $A\in\mathcal F$ to its unique element in $C$

Comment: What do you reference with this notation?:$\left \{ \left \langle A,a \right \rangle:a\in A \right \} $

Comment: @LauraVelasquez This is the set of ordered pairs $\langle A,a\rangle$ in which the first component is $A$ and the second component is an element $a$ of $A$. So it's a set in one-to-one correspondence with$A$ (by the map $a\mapsto\langle A,a\rangle$), but the family of all these sts of pairs, for various $A$'s, is always disjointed.

Comment: Very nice........+1